# Is there any option to import my excel to Views?

Tags: views, importing-exporting

I am new for drupal 7.

I got exported excel from view using Views Data Export Module.

My question is,

Is there is any option to import my excel sheet to view.

Kindly help me to achieve this...

Answer (score 1):

You can do by using [PHP Excel](https://www.drupal.org/project/phpexcel) module. This module is for handling the export or import of Excel files.

Comment: i just installed PHPExcel module with my project, How to enable import option in View?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use feeds module to import csv files into nodes. Then you create any view you want from the newly created nodes.